# Acompanhar pergunta sem favoritar?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Como acompanho o desenrolar de uma pergunta sem favoritá-la?

Answer (score 3):

Não faz. Alguma forma de favorito precisa ser usada, seja do site, do navegador ou até algo externo que fique monitorando. Pode ter alguma extensão que ajude que alguém fez, mas ainda estará favoritando. Fora isso, deixa ela aberta o tempo todo em uma aba e vai lá olhar se mudou algo.

A que deve trazer melhor resultado é favoritar pelo site que pode te notificar de forma simples, embora não incisivamente.

Comment: Encontrei o http://blunderboy.github.io/stackeye/ mas está off, e é duplicada, obrigado pela sua sapiência.